# PEStudio DLL analysis: flag in export section

Tags: debugging, binary-analysis, dll

I start to use PEStudio for DLL analysis; I understand (more or less) everything, except the "exports (flag)" section:
[image]

What does it mean the X in the flag column? So, what is a/the flag?

Thanks to all

Comment: Which manual? I just see the slides on winitor.com. Happy to hear that exists a manual...

Comment: Thanks a lot rce!